# How can I get VolatileHighlights to work with evil-yank, evil-delete, etc?

Tags: evil, advice, highlighting

With the [guide on extending Emacs](http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-tutor3.html), I discovered the [volatile highlights package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VolatileHighlights).

But it only works on Emacs operations like kill and yank. I would like to use it with Evil operations like `evil-yank` `evil-delete`, and `evil-paste-after`.

I thought about advising those functions with `defadvice`, but that didn't work.  Any other suggestions for getting it working with Evil?

Comment: Post the advice please. Maybe we can fix it.

Comment: I had the `defadvice` that calls the yank operation after the evil-yank, in order to trigger defadvice. But then it yanked two times, which was not the intention.

Comment: Please just add the advice to the question. If you do, we can fix it (probably). If you don't we won't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the source code of `volatile-highlights` and you'll find you don't need advice at all, supporting any command is built into `volatile-highlights`. All you need is two lines of code:

```lisp
(vhl/define-extension 'my-evil-highlights 'evil-yank 'evil-move 'some-other-functions ...)
(vhl/install-extension 'my-evil-highlights)
```

Read the docs for the two functions above for more info.

Comment: Error: `[vhl] No load function for extension  \`vhl/use-my-evil-highlights-extension-p'`. I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: Hmm. Works for me without errors ```(vhl/define-extension 'ut 'undo-tree-redo 'undo-tree-undo)
  (vhl/load-extension 'ut)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working in my case: http://pastebin.com/hUMDvEdM I looked up the commands that get called when press `y` or `p` or `d` in Evil, and added it to the list of `my-evil-highlights`. I don't get any error message, and I see no highlighting at all. Only when I do undo-operations. So I'm wondering what I'm missing here yet.

Comment: The code in your paste works fine for me. I evaluated the two lines, enabled volatile-highlights-mode and then ran evil-paste-after and the pasted text was highlighted.

Comment: @JordonBiondo ah. Apparently my error is generated when your code is run _after_ `volatile-highlights-mode` is enabled. It works for me now.

Comment: After reading PythonNut answer, I tried it out. And yes, after running Emacs, you need to enable Volatile-highlights-mode, then it will run. Jordon, thanks for your answer. I have validated it. Congrats with your 5000 points!